# Image loading using openGL, SOIL

Tags: image, opengl, textures, glut, soil

I tried a lot of examples for loading and displaying images in openGL using SOIL.
while running the source code below, it displays just a wite quad without an image.
I tried to open an image called: foto.
I placed the image-file in the folder of the program.

```
bool* keyStates = new bool[256];
GLuint texture[0];

void resize(int height, int width) {
    const float ar = (float) width / (float) height;
    glViewport(0, 10, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glFrustum(-ar, ar, -1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 90.0);
    //gluLookAt(0, 2, 0, -1, 1, -3, 0, 1, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity() ;
}
void keyOperations (void) {
    if (!keyStates['a']) {}
}
static void Draw(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-5.0f);
    texture[0] = SOIL_load_OGL_texture // load an image file directly as a new OpenGL texture
    (
        "foto.png",
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
    );
// allocate a texture name

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void keyPressed (unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    keyStates[key] = false;
}
void keyUp (unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    keyStates[key] = true;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("ugh fml");
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyPressed);
    glutKeyboardUpFunc(keyUp);
    /////////////////////////////////////
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Is `texture[0]` non-zero after the `SOIL_load_OGL_texture()` call?  If it *is* zero what does `SOIL_last_result()` return?

Comment: When I put in: cout<<SOIL_LAST_RESULT( ) after the the texture load it says unable to load file, but my image is png-format and is in the folder of the project or do I have to do something special with the image?

Comment: Also note that the length the `texture` array is zero.

Comment: Is the lengthh of an texture array other than a normal c++ array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a relative path to access `foto.png`.

Make sure your [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is where you expect.

Some IDEs like to change the working directory to someplace *other* than where the executable is.

Comment: Thanks, I looked around for this, do you need a special library for those functions wich sets the directory correctly?

Comment: Look into `chdir()`, though it would be easier to fix the IDE config.