# image with openGL, SOIL

Tags: image, opengl, png, textures, glut

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image loading using openGL, SOIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222312/image-loading-using-opengl-soil)

while running the source code below, it displays just a wite quad without an image.
I tried to open an image called: foto.
I placed the image-file in the folder of the program.

```
bool* keyStates = new bool[256];
GLuint texture[0];

void resize(int height, int width) {
    const float ar = (float) width / (float) height;
    glViewport(0, 10, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glFrustum(-ar, ar, -1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 90.0);
    //gluLookAt(0, 2, 0, -1, 1, -3, 0, 1, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity() ;
}
void keyOperations (void) {
    if (!keyStates['a']) {}
}
static void Draw(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-5.0f);
    texture[0] = SOIL_load_OGL_texture // load an image file directly as a new OpenGL texture
    (
        "foto.png",
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
    );
// allocate a texture name

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void keyPressed (unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    keyStates[key] = false;
}
void keyUp (unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    keyStates[key] = true;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("ugh fml");
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyPressed);
    glutKeyboardUpFunc(keyUp);
    /////////////////////////////////////
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the same behavior if the image file (foto.png) is not located in the program's working directory. But when I add the image to the program's working directory, the quad is textured properly. Try either 1) adding the texture image to the program's working directory or 2) changing the program's working directory to the directory where the texture file is located.